# Export AJAX to external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to export a ajax function to an external .js file, but for some reason its not working for me.

I have this code in the header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      var ip = $("#ip").val();
      var format = $("#format").val();
      var url = $("#url").val();
      var title = $("#title").val();
      var poststring = 'http://' + ip + '?streamformat=' + format + '&url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&title=' + title;

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: poststring,
        //data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });
      alert('Sending ' + title);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

And this code in the body of a html file.

```
<form>
    <input id="ip" value="192.168.1.1"><br>
    <input id="format" value="mp4"><br>
    <input id="url" value="http://somelink.com/file.mp4"><br>
    <input id="title" value="Video title"><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If I copy the js code to a file called ajax.js and include it, just as I do with jquery, its not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you have any errors displayed in the JavaScript console of your browser? Does the request for the JavaScript file show up in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools? What about the request for the Ajax URI? Does your HTML validate?

Comment: You should be able to put the contents of the SCRIPT tag into another file, then update your SCRIPT tag with a SRC pointed at the new file. Did you have an incorrect path to the new file?

Comment: When I press the submit button it changes the link in the address bar to http://domain.dk/ajax.htm?submit=Submit. It dosent seem to load the js file, in debug window when I use <script src="ajax.js"></script>, and ajax.htm and ajax.js is placed in same dir

Comment: It is loaing ajax.js - my bad, but for some reason the function is not working

Comment: make sure `<script src="ajax.js"></script>` comes after `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

Comment: ajax.js comes after jquery-1.9.1.js since it needs functions from that javascript - but still not working

Answer (score 0):

It turned out i rushed is a bit, and only checked my coding.
I left this code in the external .js file - and thats why it didnt work :/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```